# sdcard write error in rufus

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, raspberry-pi3

I tried to write raspbian operating system to my sdcard.
I put my sdcard into sdcard reader and then tried to format it to fat32.
I can not do that with microsoft windows, so I downloaded [sdformatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/) and my sdcard formatted successfully.

After that , I tried to write raspbian dd image into my sdcard, but I get an error and in logs I had:

```
Rufus version: 2.2.668
Windows version: Windows 10 64-bit
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.03/2014-10-06
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.02~beta2
Locale ID: 0x0409
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic- Multi-Card USB Device' (0BDA:0158)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Sector Size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, TracksPerCylinder: 255, SectorsPerTrack: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x00000000
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 (0x0b)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8048869376 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Scanning image...
'G:\2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img' doesn't look like an ISO image
Image has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
'G:\2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img' is a bootable disk image
Using image: 2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img

Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Opened drive \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 for write access
Will use 'F:' as volume mountpoint
I/O boundary checks disabled
Analyzing existing boot records...
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Volume has an unknown Partition Boot Record
Deleting partitions...
Clearing MBR/PBR/GPT structures...
Erasing 128 sectors
Writing Image...
write error: [0x00000002] The system cannot find the file specified.
  RETRYING...
write error: [0x00000002] The system cannot find the file specified.
  RETRYING...
write error: [0x00000037] The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

0 devices found
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic- Multi-Card USB Device' (0BDA:0158)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Sector Size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, TracksPerCylinder: 255, SectorsPerTrack: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x00000001
Drive does not have an x86 Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: Small FAT16 (0x04)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8053063680 bytes)
  Start Sector: 0, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic- Multi-Card USB Device' (0BDA:0158)
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x81
Disk type: Removable, Sector Size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, TracksPerCylinder: 255, SectorsPerTrack: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x00000001
Drive does not have an x86 Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: Small FAT16 (0x04)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8053063680 bytes)
  Start Sector: 0, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic- Multi-Card USB Device' (0BDA:0158)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Sector Size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, TracksPerCylinder: 255, SectorsPerTrack: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 2
Disk ID: 0x623FDBF4
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 63 MB (66060288 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Partition 2:
  Type: GNU/Linux (0x83)
  Size: 4 GB (4301258752 bytes)
  Start Sector: 137216, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic- Multi-Card USB Device' (0BDA:0158)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Sector Size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, TracksPerCylinder: 255, SectorsPerTrack: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 2
Disk ID: 0x623FDBF4
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 63 MB (66060288 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
Partition 2:
  Type: GNU/Linux (0x83)
  Size: 4 GB (4301258752 bytes)
  Start Sector: 137216, Boot: No, Recognized: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi has its own method of writing to the SD card. I would try that method to reduce the chance of write errors. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md

It uses [a specific program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to write the image, which needs to be ran as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the official tool](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) "Raspberry Pi Imager" worked fine for me.

Also, be sure to not use USB 3.0 card reader (2.0 recommended).